# C - invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void (*)()’

Tags: c, linux, g++, void

I am getting the following when I try to compile my program:

```
invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void (*)()’

initializing argument 2 of ‘void makecontext(ucontext_t*, void (*)(), int, ...)’ [-fpermissive]

invalid conversion from ‘void (*)()’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive] init_TCB(tcb,function,stack,STACK_SIZE);
initializing argument 2 of ‘void init_TCB(TCB_t*, void*, void*, int)’ [-fpermissive]
void init_TCB (TCB_t *tcb, void *function, void *stackP, int stack_size)`
```

These are the lines of code that are causing the errors:

```
#include <ucontext.h>

typedef struct TCB_t {
   struct TCB_t     *next;
   struct TCB_t     *prev;
   ucontext_t      context;
} TCB_t; 

void init_TCB (TCB_t *tcb, void *function, void *stackP, int stack_size)
{
   memset(tcb, '\0', sizeof(TCB_t));       
   getcontext(&tcb->context);      
   tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_sp = stackP;
   tcb->context.uc_stack.ss_size = (size_t) stack_size;
   makecontext(&tcb->context, function, 0);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A "generic pointer" (`void *`) can not be implicitly converted to a "pointer to function" (of any type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `void *function` but `void*` is not a correct type of a function pointer.  `void (*)()` is a type of a function pointer, so probably you should change your function signature:

```
void init_TCB (TCB_t *tcb, void (*function)(), void *stackP, int stack_size)
```